# MS SQL Try Catch Transastion

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I need to know if the sql below is correct to roll back if something bad happens.

I first create a temp table

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#LocalSummery') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #LocalSummery  
CREATE TABLE  #LocalSummery (
```

then I populate the table

```
insert into #LocalSummery'
SELECT *....
```

then i start my try catch

```
BEGIN TRY
 BEGIN TRANSACTION 

delete from LocalSummeryRealTable
INSERT INTO LocalSummeryRealTable
SELECT S.*
FROM  #LocalSummery'    AS S 
COMMIT

END TRY

BEGIN CATCH


       IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
              ROLLBACK TRANSACTION 
...
```

I noticed when i did the insert into the LocalSummeryRealTable the fields didn't line up and I got an error.  I expected things to roll back but in SSMS query window it gave me a message that the trans wasn't committed and asked me if I wanted to commit it.  Why would this ask me when it should of been rolled back?

Comment: Shoudlnt your commit be if @@tranccount is not > 0.

Comment: Also what is the purpose if try catch if you are using transactions.... I am actually asking this question for my own info.

Comment: @logixologist `BEGIN TRANSACTION` increments `@@TRANCOUNT` by 1, so when the `COMMIT` gets hit in the syntax above, it will be `1`. I believe OP's attempted logic is "Try the following... if we get to the final line without error, then we commit. If there is error, kick us into the CATCH portion. If we begun the transaction, roll it back."

Comment: I've always done a rollback if @@error is > 0.

Comment: @Santi is that even necessary?

Comment: Can you try moving your `BEGIN TRANSACTION` *above* your `BEGIN TRY`?

Comment: other issues happen when I move it to high up in the SP. i would think the rollback would happen on error of any kind

Comment: It's strange that the transaction isn't committed. For safety SET XACT_ABORT  ON at the very beginning.  When the  batch finishes, the Database Engine rolls back any active uncommittable transactions. Remove the select from the  transaction, for it may be slow or locked to delay the committing.

Comment: what line do you think i need to remove? select from the transaction? what's that line?